# Can't get urlConnection.getInputStream() using Tablet

Tags: android, request, httpurlconnection, tablet

I have a strange situation. All requests work fine when using telephones and virtual device but if I try to use Tablet nothing works.

My request:

```
String path = "https://...";
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
try{
    URL url = new URL(path);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
            .openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection = Tools.setHeader(urlConnection);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);

    LOG.debug("Start input stream");
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
    LOG.debug("Input stream exist "+inputStream.toString());

    String response = Tools.streamToString(inputStream);
    inputStream.close();
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
```

I don't get any error messages. Using the proxy server I see that my request send and the response received. But in the program `urlConnection.getInputStream()` method get nothing. The program does not go further. I do not see the second log.

I tried to set timeouts, but this didn't help. The response comes quickly (1-2 seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Heyy I run with my following code on both mobile or tablet. I am providing you my code have a look on it.

Code :

```
 public class URLConnectionCheck extends Activity {

TextView resultText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_urlconnection_check);

     resultText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.resultTextView);

    new AsynchTaskTest().execute();

}

private class AsynchTaskTest extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String path = "http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two";

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader=null;

        try{
            URL url = new URL(path);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line = "";

            while((line = reader.readLine()) !=null) {
                buffer.append(line+"\n");

            }

            return buffer.toString();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        resultText.setText(aVoid);
    }
}
```

}

And result is on my screens as::

[image: mobile screenshot]

[image: tablet screenshot]

Comment: Ankit, this is not related to the request, since the request may or may not work,  at some point I don't get the response to the program, although I see the response exists. Apparently, this is some kind of problem associated with the tablet settings or foreground process. At the moment, everything works well, although I did not change anything, and then in another time it stops working. I have a long process in foreground mode. Thank you for your efforts to find a solution, I added you a plus!